# Why my output in JSON data contain extra curly braces

Tags: php, mysql, json

The main problem of this  code is that it provides extra curly braces ..

```
<?php   
header('Content-Type: json');
include('config.php');

    for($i=1990;$i<=2016;$i++){
        $sum=0;
        $data1=array();
        $result=mysql_query("select * from crimedetails  where crime_year=$i");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
          {
            $sum+=$row['crime_mudered'];
            $data['crime_mudered']=$sum;
            $data['crime_year']=$row['crime_year'];
            }
          $data3[]=$data;
    }           
    array_push($data1,$data3);
    print json_encode($data1);
?>
```

Output data:
[image]

Comment: you're getting EXACTLY what you asked for. a bunch of query result rows (`$data`) inside an array (`$data3`) inside ANOTHER array (`$data1`).

Comment: Without using array_push ..it works fine..thanks

Answer (score 0):

just use array_merge() instead of array_push()

Comment: just use array_merge() instead of array_push() when i use array_merge() it hide all data

Answer (score 0):

When you apply `json_encode()` to an associative array, the brackets become curly braces. That is because it is encoding that array to become a **JavaScript Object Notation** (JSON). So, in JavaScript, associative arrays are **objects with properties**. And, to define an object with properties in JavaScript, you use **curly braces** (`{}`).

Answer (score -1):

```
$responsehead=array("ResponseData"=>
                            array(
                                "status" => 1,
                                "ResponseMsg" => "Category values listed"),
                                "Category"=>$responsedetails);
                                
                            echo json_encode($responsehead);
```

you can try like above. `$responsedetails` is an array which contains response data from db.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).